# Normalize Column Values by Monthly Averages with added Group dimension

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

## Initial Note

I already got this running, but it takes a very long time to execute. My DataFrame is around 500MB large. I am hoping to hear some feedback on how to execute this as quickly as possible.

## Problem Statement

I want to normalize the DataFrame columns by the `mean` of the column's values during each month. An added complexity is that I have a column named `group` which denotes a different sensor in which the parameter (column) was measured. Therefore, the analysis needs to iterate around `group` and each month.

#### DF example

```
                     X  Y  Z  group 
2019-02-01 09:30:07  1  2  1  'grp1'
2019-02-01 09:30:23  2  4  3  'grp2'
2019-02-01 09:30:38  3  6  5  'grp1'
                ...
```

#### Code (Functional, but slow)

This is the code that I used. Coding annotations provide descriptions of most lines. I recognize that the three for loops are causing this runtime issue, but I do not have the foresight to see a way around it. Does anyone know any

```py
    # Get mean monthly values for each group
    mean_per_month_unit = process_df.groupby('group').resample('M', how='mean')
    # Store the monthly dates created in last line into a list called month_dates
    month_dates = mean_per_month_unit.index.get_level_values(1)
    # Place date on multiIndex columns. future note: use df[DATE, COL_NAME][UNIT] to access mean value
    mean_per_month_unit = mean_per_month_unit.unstack().swaplevel(0,1,1).sort_index(axis=1)

    divide_df = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df)
    process_cols.remove('group')
    for grp in group_list:
        print(grp)
        # Iterate through month
        for mnth in month_dates:
            # Make mask where month and group
            mask = (df.index.month == mnth.month) & (df['group'] == grp)
            for col in process_cols:
                # Set values of divide_df 
                divide_df.iloc[mask.tolist(), divide_df.columns.get_loc(col)] = mean_per_month_unit[mnth, col][grp]
    # Divide process_df with divide_df
    final_df = process_df / divide_df.values
```

## EDIT: Example data

Here is the [data](https://pastebin.com/QVeqEV67) in CSV format.

## EDIT2: Current code (according to current answer)

```py
def normalize_df(df):

    df['month'] = df.index.month
    print(df['month'])
    df['year'] = df.index.year
    print(df['year'])

    def find_norm(x, df_col_list): # x is a row in dataframe, col_list is the list of columns to normalize
        agg = df.groupby(by=['group', 'month', 'year'], as_index=True).mean()
        print("###################", x.name, x['month'])
        for column in df_col_list: # iterate over col list, find mean from aggregations, and divide the value by
            print(column)
            mean_col = agg.loc[(x['group'], x['month'], x['year']), column]
            print(mean_col)
            col_name = "norm" + str(column)
            x[col_name] = x[column] / mean_col # norm

        return x

    normalize_cols = df.columns.tolist()
    normalize_cols.remove('group')
    #normalize_cols.remove('mode')
    df2 = df.apply(find_norm, df_col_list = normalize_cols, axis=1)
```

The code runs perfectly for one iteration and then it fails with the error:

```
KeyError: ('month', 'occurred at index 2019-02-01 11:30:17')
```

As I said, it runs correctly once. However, it iterates over the same row again and then fails. I see according to df.apply() documentation that the first row always runs twice. I'm just not sure why this fails on the second time through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the requirement is to group the columns by `mean` and the `month`, here is another approach:

1. Create new columns - month and year from the index. df.index.month can be used for this provided the index is of type DatetimeIndex

```py
    type(df.index) # df is the original dataframe
    #pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

    df['month'] = df.index.month
    df['year'] = df.index.year # added year assuming the grouping occurs per grp per month per year. No need to add this column if year is not to be considered.
```

2. Now, group over `(grp, month, year)` and aggregate to find mean of every column. (Added year assuming the grouping occurs per grp per month per year. No need to add this column if year is not to be considered.)

```py
    agg = df.groupby(by=['grp', 'month', 'year'], as_index=True).mean()
```

3. Use a function to calculate the normalized values and use `apply()` over the original dataframe

```py
def find_norm(x, df_col_list): # x is a row in dataframe, col_list is the list of columns to normalize

    for column in df_col_list: # iterate over col list, find mean from aggregations, and divide the value by the mean. 
        mean_col = agg.loc[(str(x['grp']), x['month'], x['year']), column]
        col_name = "norm" + str(column)
        x[col_name] = x[column] / mean_col # norm

    return x

df2 = df.apply(find_norm, df_col_list = ['A','B','C'], axis=1)
#df2 will now have 3 additional columns - normA, normB, normC
```

```
df2:

                        A   B   C   grp month year  normA     normB     normC
2019-02-01 09:30:07     1   2   3   1   2   2019    0.666667    0.8     1.5
2019-03-02 09:30:07     2   3   4   1   3   2019    1.000000    1.0     1.0
2019-02-01 09:40:07     2   3   1   2   2   2019    1.000000    1.0     1.0
2019-02-01 09:38:07     2   3   1   1   2   2019    1.333333    1.2     0.5
```

Alternatively, for step 3, one can `join` the `agg` and `df` dataframes and find the norm. 
Hope this helps!

Here is how the code would look like:

```py
# Step 1
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year # added year assuming the grouping occurs 

# Step 2
agg = df.groupby(by=['grp', 'month', 'year'], as_index=True).mean()

# Step 3
def find_norm(x, df_col_list): # x is a row in dataframe, col_list is the list of columns to normalize

    for column in df_col_list: # iterate over col list, find mean from aggregations, and divide the value by the mean. 
        mean_col = agg.loc[(str(x['grp']), x['month'], x['year']), column]
        col_name = "norm" + str(column)
        x[col_name] = x[column] / mean_col # norm

    return x

df2 = df.apply(find_norm, df_col_list = ['A','B','C'], axis=1)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @saurjog for the wholesome answer! I was trying to replicate this on my data but was having a hard time. Could you replicate this with the data that I linked in the post (just added data in an Edit). If successful, could you also provide the full code that you utilized?

Comment: @BeardedDork The difference that I see is the index. I'm not sure if the csv that you pointed to is `DatetimeIndexed`. If that is not the case, you can replace the `.index.<method>` with the appropriate date column in the dataframe. Additionally,  `df_col_list ` in `df2 = df.apply(find_norm, df_col_list = ['A','B','C'], axis=1)` should contain all the columns from a ... k. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @saurjog. I had already made these adjustments. However, I am receiving an unexpected error. I edited the post. Thanks again for the continued help!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @BeardedDork. Not sure why this error occurs. Shall try myself today, but feel free to post this error as a new question to get more answers!

Comment: @BeardedDork I think the error is with this line: `normalize_cols = df.columns.tolist()` With this line, the columns `month` and `year` are getting added to `normalize_cols` which are not present in `aggregated` dataframe. Hence the error on `month`. Hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it! I'm wondering if this could be made faster by not having to calculate the mean every time it iterates through a row. I'll accept this answer. Thanks for the continuous help!

Comment: @BeardedDork yes, we can calculate means in a separate dataframe like in step 2 of the answer (`agg` dataframe). So, in the function, we just locate the mean from the dataframe. (See usage of `agg` in step 3 of the answer). I have updated the answer with full code which may help you.